# BeautifulSoup get only the "general" text in a td tag, and nothing in nested tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Say that my html looks like this:

```
<td>Potato1 <span somestuff...>Potato2</span></td>
...
<td>Potato9 <span somestuff...>Potato10</span></td>
```

I have beautifulsoup doing this:

```
for tag in soup.find_all("td"):
    print tag.text
```

And I get

```
Potato1 Potato2
....
Potato9 Potato10
```

Would it be possible to just get the text that's inside the  tag but not any text nested inside the span tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) as

```
>>> for tag in soup.find_all("td"):
...     print tag.contents[0]
...
Potato1
Potato9
```

**What it does?**

A tags children are available as a list using the `.contents`.

```
>>> for tag in soup.find_all("td"):
...     print tag.contents
...
[u'Potato1 ', <span somestuff...="">Potato2</span>]
[u'Potato9 ', <span somestuff...="">Potato10</span>]
```

since we are only interested in the first element, we go for

```
print tag.contents[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method, which, unlike `tag.contents[0]` guarantees that the text is a
`NavigableString` and not text from within a child `Tag`, is:

```
[child for tag in soup.find_all("td") 
 for child in tag if isinstance(child, bs.NavigableString)]
```

---

Here is an example which highlights the difference:

```
import bs4 as bs

content = '''
<td>Potato1 <span>Potato2</span></td>
<td><span>FOO</span></td>
<td><span>Potato10</span>Potato9</td>
'''
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content)

print([tag.contents[0] for tag in soup.find_all("td")])
# [u'Potato1 ', <span>FOO</span>, <span>Potato10</span>]

print([child for tag in soup.find_all("td") 
       for child in tag if isinstance(child, bs.NavigableString)])
# [u'Potato1 ', u'Potato9']
```

---

Or, with lxml, you could use the XPath `td/text()`:

```
import lxml.html as LH

content = '''
<td>Potato1 <span>Potato2</span></td>
<td><span>FOO</span></td>
<td><span>Potato10</span>Potato9</td>
'''
root = LH.fromstring(content)

print(root.xpath('td/text()'))
```

yields

```
['Potato1 ', 'Potato9']
```